# Как разбить строку на все возможные комбинации подстрок

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которая принимает строку. 
На выходе она должна вернуть все комбинации подстрок этой строки.
Пример "строка" - > "с", "т", "р", "о", "к", "а", "ст", "стр", "стро", "строк", "тр", "тро" и т.д.
Я сделал так. Какие ещё есть варианты?

```
function comb(str) {
            var arr = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                for(var j = (i+1); j < (str.length+1); j++) {
                    arr.push(str.substring(i, j));
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }
```

Comment: рекурсия, с проходом строки от i до length-1-i, где i - входной параметр увеличивается постоянно и изначально равен 0

Comment: добавил правку.

Comment: У вас очипятка: не `lenght` а `length`

Comment: спасибо. нашел.

Comment: у вас не все комбинации будут, кстати.. из за i+1

Comment: str.length надо поменять на (str.length+1). уже понял.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Один из вариантов рекурсии:

```js
function test(str) { 
  if (str.length < 1) 
      return;
  
  for (var j = 0; j < str.length; ++j) {
      console.log(str.substr(0, j + 1));
  } 
 
  test(str.substr(1, j + 1));
}

test("Строка");
```

Для складирования оного в результирующий массив:

```
function test(str, arr) {   
    if (str.length < 1) 
        return;

    for (var j = 0; j < str.length; ++j) {
        arr.push(str.substr(0, j + 1));
    }   

    test(str.substr(1, j + 1), arr);    
}

var myResultArr = [];
test("Строка", myResultArr);
```